# Sql: using table's column value as a parameter for the stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

So I want to create a table with two columns. The first column has studentIDs and the other column has GPA for that corresponding student. I have a stored procedure called sp_calculateGPA that looks up student's grades based on their student ID and calculates their GPA.

Can I use the first column value as a parameter for the stored procedure to get the GPA value for the second column? If yes, how can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: How are you executing the SP? Are you trying to pass one studentId at a time?

Comment: Sounds like you probably want a scalar function instead of a stored proc for that

Comment: @ron tornambe -  Yes, I want to pass one student at a time.

Comment: Kateract - Can you please give me an example of how I could use a scalar function?

Comment: Please show us your SP code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a stored procedure that takes in `@StudentID INT` and then does:

`SELECT GPA FROM tableName WHERE studentID = @StudentID`

If you need to do summing and averaging of the grades you can group by the studentID and use aggregate functions such as `SUM` and `COUNT`

Comment: That's exactly what I have in my stored procedure. But I need to make sure that the table that the procedure creates has a studentID on the left column and on the right column has the GPA for that student. How do I do that?

Comment: If you mean the returned results you can just do `SELECT studentID, GPA...` and the first column will be ID and the second would be GPA